# How do I set default accounts for YouTube and GMail?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

How do I set default accounts for YouTube and GMail?

I have an email for school and an email for personal use. How can I make it so that, in Chrome, when I go to YouTube it logs me into my personal account but when I go to GMail it logs me into my school account?